# How to remove this error while installing numpy on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, pip, numpy

I am getting this exception while trying to install numpy. I have tried both by directly calling pip(command: pip install numpy) and through sudo as well. 
Please help resolve this:

```
    fareha@fareha-Inspiron-5537:~$ sudo pip install numpy scipy
    [sudo] password for fareha: 
    The directory '/home/fareha/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory  is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
    The directory '/home/fareha/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
    Collecting numpy
    Downloading numpy-1.14.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (12.1MB)
76% |████████████████████████▍       | 9.3MB 3.2kB/s eta 0:14:49Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 577, in _prepare_file
session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 810, in unpack_url
hashes=hashes
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 649, in unpack_http_url
hashes)
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 871, in _download_http_url
_download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 595, in _download_url
hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/hashes.py", line 46, in check_against_chunks
for chunk in chunks:
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 563, in written_chunks
for chunk in chunks:
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/ui.py", line 139, in iter
for x in it:
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 552, in resp_read
decode_content=False):
    File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 344, in stream
data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
     File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 311, in read
flush_decoder = True
     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
     File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 240, in _error_catcher
raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
     ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Comment: @user68186 not related to the error observed

Comment: It looks like your system isn't able to connect to PyPI, are you on a network which has a proxy requirement or some other type of setup in which your system has its traffic filtered?

Comment: Plenty of python libs are installable via apt: `sudo apt-get install python-numpy` or `sudo apt-get install python3-numpy`.

Comment: I have had this issue in the past and it was due to the version of pip. Can you run `pip install --upgrade pip` and try again?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy and Scipy for Python 2.x can be installed from the default repositories with the following commands:

```
sudo apt install python-numpy # 20.04 and earlier
sudo apt install python-scipy # 18.04 and earlier
```

The corresponding packages for Python 3.x are python3-numpy and python3-scipy.